# Displaying number of even and odd number

Tags: java

We have an assignment in programming we have to make a program that will have the output below. The given values are (5,3,6,7,44,8,12,23,9,0) the number 0 should not be counted.
Can anyone tell me if my program is correct or needs changes if so please help.

The number of even numbers: 4
The even numbers are: 6 44 8 12 
The number of odd numbers: 5
The odd numbers are: 5 3 7 23 9

```
    int array[] = {5,3,6,7,44,8,12,23,9,0};
    int evenNumbers[] = new int[array.length];
    int oddNumbers[] = new int[array.length];
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    //This will count the number of even except 0  
    for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
        if(array[i] == 0)
            break;
        if(array[i]%2 == 0)
        even++;
        else
        odd++;             
    } 
    //This will put the even or odd numbers on their array
     for(int a = 0; a < array.length ; a++)
     {
       if(array[a]%2 == 0)
          evenNumbers[a] = array[a];

       else 
          oddNumbers[a] = array[a];

    }

    System.out.println("THE NUMBER OF EVEN NUMBERS ARE: "+even);
    System.out.print("THE EVEN NUMBERS ARE: ");

    //This will output the non zero values off evenNumbers[]
    for(int evenN = 0; evenN< array.length ; evenN++){

        if(evenNumbers[evenN]!= 0){
    System.out.print(" "+evenNumbers[evenN]);
        }       
   }     
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("THE NUMBER OF ODD NUMBERS ARE: "+odd);
    System.out.print("THE ODD NUMBERS ARE: ");
    for(int oddN = 0; oddN < array.length ; oddN++){

       //This will output the non zero values off oddNumbers[]
        if(oddNumbers[oddN]!= 0){
        System.out.print(" "+oddNumbers[oddN]);

        }
    }  

    }
}
```

Comment: No question should ever start with "we have an assignment". It defeats the object of learning.

Comment: Why do you ask us to check the program, if you could easily do it yourself? You know which of those are even numbers. Does your program print the right things out? If yes, good job. If no, debug.

Comment: Did you run the program and checked whether or not the outcome is what you think the outcome should be?

Comment: At least, the OP made the code. So much OPs ask us to do their homeworks... That said, to improve this code, I would make a unit test and I would add curly brackets on `if` statements (`for`, `if`, `while`, `else` statements without curly brackets are evil)

Comment: Why so much  -1? The OP tried something and shows us for improvement.

Comment: ask questions for learning purpose

Comment: is there any way to prevent the 0 from being counted as an even?

Answer (score 0):

You should not ask these kind of questions here. But any how this will help you,

Instead of two for-loop you can merge it into 1 like,

```
for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
    if(array[i] == 0)
        continue; //Skipping 0 but continue for Non-Zero
    if(array[i]%2 == 0)
    {
        evenNumbers[even] = array[i];//Copy Even number into even array
        even++;
    }
    else
    {
       oddNumbers[odd] = array[i];//Copy Odd number into Odd array
       odd++;             
    } 
}

//This will output the non zero values off evenNumbers[]
for(int evenN = 0; evenN< evenNumbers.length ; evenN++){
    //No need of this check here.//if(evenNumbers[evenN]!= 0)
    System.out.print(" "+evenNumbers[evenN]);     
}
```